# Rails is searching for .erb views instead of .haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails is giving a 500 error (in a production environment using Passenger). The production log says that the it is missing the view:

```
Started GET "/" for at 2012-05-12 20:34:18 +0200
Processing by EventCalendarsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template event_calendars/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:it], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/regroup/calendar/app/views"
  * "/home/regroup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/event_calendars_controller.rb:24:in `index'
```

I'm sure the `bundle install` installed both `haml` and `haml-rails` gems. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

What's wrong here? Do I need to change something to make this work in a production environment?

Comment: Please do not post your code by linking to it externally, instead post it here and use the proper formatting. If the linked resource goes away this question becomes useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace the `gem 'haml-rails'` out of assets group and put it under the  `gem 'cancan'`

Comment: Suborx you made my day! Thanks!
It fixed the problem. I'm going to learn more about :assets block and what should I put there.

Thank you, your answers have been really helpful and detailed!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rails assets guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails), the assets group in bundler should only be used for:

> Gems used only for assets and not required in production environments by default.

You should take the `gem 'haml-rails'` out of the assets group.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to read it.
This is the 1st rails app, and I needed to develop it in a week, so I've had few time to read the whole doc. My fault.